# Navigation in forms group is not active in access 2013

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a navigation form in MS Access 2013, but when i open cteate tab i find navigation in forms group not active.

[image: Navigation Form]

Answer (score 0):

Navigation forms are a part of the actual Access format .accdb
So you will not be able to create navigation subforms until you save your database from mdb to accdb.
Simple `save as` should do the trick.